# Visualforce Input Field Issue?

Tags: visualforce, field-level-security

I have this situation: One common apex:inputField, but at my org(production) this field it's not showing and at sandbox this works. Anyone know why?
An example of my field :

```
<apex:inputField id="dataEntrada" value="{!objetoC.Data__c}" showDatePicker="true" styleClass="dataEntrada datasSearch" />
```

Any possible help it's welcome
Regards

Comment: Visualforce honors Field Level Security. Please check your custom field's security settings to make sure your profile has access to it.

Comment: To add to sfdcfox's comment, simply deploying a field to production won't carry over the Field Level Security from one org to another.

Comment: My field in my org was set 'invisible'.Thanks for the help.